# What is the antonym of "to friend"?

Tags: word-request, verbs, antonyms

The verb *to friend* is used for making friends in social nets connecting people with similar interests. What is the antonym, the negative verb, meaning *to delete somebody from your "friends"*? What's the correct prefix? I found different versions on the Internet.

Comment: Are you talking about on Facebook and other social media sites specifically?

Comment: to unfriend, naturally

Comment: @Catija, yes, which one to choose --to unfriend, because there's *unfriendly * or to defriend, (reminding *defrost *)?

Comment: A good search line for Google is "friend antonym" or "[any word] antonym".

Comment: Obviously, it's *to enemy* a person. (Just kidding!)

Comment: @ErikE, it would probably be more like *to foe* a person.

Comment: @Peanut *Enemy* and *foe* are synonyms.

Comment: @ErikE, it sounds more correct when saying "*to foe* a person" rather than "*to enemy* a person".

Comment: @Peanut I disagree. They both sound equally incorrect. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for *unfriend*.

> [unfriend](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfriend)
>   to remove (someone) from a list of designated friends on a person's social networking Web site

And apparently, *defriend* works too.

> [defriend](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defriend)
>   unfriend

I've also heard people use the words *delete* and *remove*.

1. I deleted him from (my) Facebook/my friends list.
2. I removed him from (my) Facebook/my friends list.

All of these options seem correct. They are all understandable.

---

I had a feeling *unfriend* was more popular than *defriend* because I do not often hear or read about people "defriending" one another. Thank you to
@AndreaGottardo for providing [additional information](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=unfriend%2C%20defriend) using Google Trends.

[image: Google Trends comparison of unfriend and defriend]

In the above graph, *unfriend* is blue while *defriend* is red.

Comment: Looks like *unfriend* is much more used compared to *defriend*. See here: https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=unfriend%2C%20defriend

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I need to learn how to use these google resources to provide more insightful answers.

Comment: I've also heard the term blocked, but it's used inappropriately. It happens that many people have their information locked down so only their friends can see their updates. Thus removing a current friend effectively blocks that person, even though that's not the actual action. Still, I hear it enough that it should be mentioned.

Comment: I have never heard "unfriend." I'm gonna take a poll of my friends who use FB. My use of *defriend* may precede FB, going back to MySpace, LiveJournal, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer [defriend](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=defriend),  but there is [unfriend](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Unfriend), which I never use. Either one can be considered "correct."

Comment: why do you prefer "defriend" over "unfriend"?

Answer (score -1):

As "to friend" might specific to certain networks (and unfriend or defriend have been proposed), you have the option to **defollow**. You can remain "friend" in some sense, but stop be informed about updates. In a more generic sense, you can **block**.